# Why does "Oedipus Rex" most commonly have a Latin rather than Greek title?

Tags: ancient-greek, word-choice

Nearly 2500 years ago, Sophocles wrote the Greek play *Oedipus the King*.

It was originally titled *Oedipus Tyrannus* in Greek.
Yet today, it is almost universally known as *Oedipus Rex*.

Why and when did the original title change from Greek to Latin?

Comment: For a simple point, the original title was in the Greek language and the Greek alphabet, which have long been less accessible than their Latin counterparts in the west. But perhaps there's more to it.

Comment: This question isn't really about Latin language, as I see it. It's about why a work of literature happens to be popularly known by a particular title among English speakers (granted that that title happens to include a Latin word). I think Literature Stack Exchange would be a better fit.

Comment: @cnread This particular case is much more than that. There is something to be said about the Latinization of Greek names in general, but with this in particular, early (Renaissance) editions used both Oedipus Tyrannus and Oedipus Rex. I can see an answer coming from that angle to be particularly fruitful. But it's an arduous slog through all the different names.

Comment: It could be relevant here if the reason for the name change was because of the meaning of _tyrannus_ itself, particularly if it was also influenced by updates to the myth by Latin-language writers (I'm thinking of Seneca's play _Oedipus_, which used neither _tyrannus_ nor _rex_ in the title).

Comment: Cf. *Iphigenia in Aulide*. I believe many Greek plays are (now) alternatively referred to by their Latin titles.

Comment: @Adam yeah, I'd definitely think the connotation of injustice associated with tyrannus in most modern languages (but not so much in Ancient Greek) could easily motivate the preference